# Remove all text from a string apart from a date

Tags: php, regex

I'm currently outputting some Whois information on a PHP template (using [this](https://github.com/regru/php-whois)) which returns a large block of text via this variable `$whois_answer`:

> Relevant dates: Registered on: 19-Aug-2015 Expiry date: 19-Aug-2025
>   Last updated: 21-Sep-2015 Registration status: Registered until expiry
>   date. Name servers: xxx.mainnameserver.com xxx.mainnameserver.com
>   WHOIS lookup made at 09:34:40 10-Nov-2017 -- This WHOIS information is
>   provided for free by Nominet UK the central registry for .uk domain
>   names. This information and the .uk WHOIS are: Copyright Nominet UK
>   1996 - 2017. You may not access the .uk WHOIS or use any data from it
>   except as permitted by the terms of use available in full at
>   http://www.nominet.uk/whoisterms, which includes restrictions on: (A)
>   use of the data for advertising, or its repackaging, recompilation,
>   redistribution or reuse (B) obscuring, removing or hiding any or all
>   of this notice and (C) exceeding query rate or volume limits. The data
>   is provided on an 'as-is' basis and may lag behind the register.
>   Access may be withdrawn or restricted at any time. Domain is
>   registered

I don't want to amend the original code, just amend the final output (as I may use other functionality at a later date).

I purely want to grab the expiry date of the domain, how can I target that and strip everything else out? Be aware that the domain is dynamic so the date could be anything but will always be in that format.

Comment: have you tried using regular expressions?

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "will always be in that format"? The WHOIS server [varies by TLD](https://github.com/regru/php-whois/blob/master/src/Phois/Whois/whois.servers.json), and the overall format can vary greatly...

Comment: Do you mean the format will always (??!) be `"Expiry date: DD-MM-YYYY"`? Or can it be, for example, `"Expiration date -- YYYY-MM-DD"`?

Comment: @TomLord I don't need it to cover all the domain possibilities, just the main few. All the ones I've checked start with `Expiry date: ` then the date follows... although the date format changes slightly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use preg_match:

```
$str ="Relevant dates: Registered on: 19-Aug-2015 Expiry date: 19-Aug-2025 Last updated: 21-Sep-2015 Registration status: Registered until expiry date. Name servers: xxx.mainnameserver.com xxx.mainnameserver.com WHOIS lookup made at 09:34:40 10-Nov-2017 -- This WHOIS information is provided for free by Nominet UK the central registry for .uk domain names. This information and the .uk WHOIS are: Copyright Nominet UK 1996 - 2017. You may not access the .uk WHOIS or use any data from it except as permitted by the terms of use available in full at http://www.nominet.uk/whoisterms, which includes restrictions on: (A) use of the data for advertising, or its repackaging, recompilation, redistribution or reuse (B) obscuring, removing or hiding any or all of this notice and (C) exceeding query rate or volume limits. The data is provided on an 'as-is' basis and may lag behind the register. Access may be withdrawn or restricted at any time. Domain is registered";

Preg_match("/Expiry date:\s([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/", $str, $match);

Echo $match[1];
```

https://3v4l.org/k7W2b

This will match "Expiry date " and then capture: `a-Z` and `0-9` and `-` meaning it will stop the capture at space.